# How to map a value to another different changing value

Tags: python, function

I would like to know how to basically connect two numbers. For example: if I have a number that goes from 0 to 10 I then would like to "map" it to another value that goes from 0 to 100 meaning that if the original number changes its value by one then my number goes up by the same percentage. Like so: original number = 1, then my number should be 10 and if it is 2 then 20 and so on.

Is there a function for that or do I have to code it manually?

Concrete example:

```
day_night_value = 5 # 0 = midnight; 10= noon
threshold = ?? # This should equal to 249 if it is noon, and 134 if it is midnight
```

does that help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may need to rephrase with a [mcve] for your inputs and outputs. What you've described so far is multiplication, in which case the operator is `*`

Comment: Thanks I will give a concrete example just a sec

Comment: In this case it sounds like a custom function, e.g., yes you will have to code it manually

Comment: was just wondering because processing (a really high level language) has this function so I was not sure but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often known as the ["map range" equation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range).

The Rosetta Stone link above gives the following [definition for Python](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range#Python):

```
def maprange( a, b, s):
    (a1, a2), (b1, b2) = a, b
    return  b1 + ((s - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1))
```

With an example of its usage:

```
for s in range(11):
    print("%2g maps to %g" % (s, maprange( (0, 10), (-1, 0), s)))
```

You can of course alter the definition to make it so you don't need to pass tuples for ranges.

This is also such a commonly required function that many graphics libraries include a definition of it.

Comment: Yep exactly what I needed. Thank you!